# httpd : If REQUEST_URI contains specific word; need to append QUERY_STRING

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, query-string, httpd.conf, request-uri

I have to append a QUERY_STRING at the end of URL while redirecting to remote server on the basis of string found in the REQUEST_URI.

My httpd.conf looks like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/site1$ 
RewriteRule ^/ /?Id=1 [QSA]
```

This is not working.
I want to add QUERY_STRING "?Id=1" if REQUEST_URI contains word "site1".
Pelase help.. Thanks.

```
Listen 9010

LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_html_module modules/mod_proxy_html.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

<IfModule proxy_html_module>
Include conf/extra/httpd-proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/site1$
        RewriteRule .* ?tenantId=1 [QSA,L]

<VirtualHost *:9010>
ServerName localhost

    ProxyPass /site1 http://localhost:7001

    ProxyPassReverse /site1 http://localhost:7001

     </VirtualHost>
```

I would be doing something wrong for sure.. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works.  If not, it should point you in the right direction.

```
   RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/site1$ 
    RewriteRule .* ?Id=1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Reenactor for reply. I have tried this. But did not work. Actually I think that rewrite is not working at all for me. The configurations that i have done is as mentioned in the question (edited)